# What's required for the lifting of a temporary question ban?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

Although it has been in place for more than a year, the only question ban I've encountered on any Stack Exchange site was a temporary one that would have supposedly allowed me to ask one more question on the Physics Stack Exchange after it would've been in place for only six months, with subsequent questions allowed if that question would appear satisfactory to the staff. The ban, never removed, resulted in my posting a question, today, on the Astronomy Stack Exchange instead.  As there would appear to have been some oversight, I'm wondering whether I'd have the option of transferring the question to the PSE site.  (I'd like to get the answer from Meta before any transfer or duplication of the question, but, if either the transfer of the question between sites or its duplication on the PSE site might be arranged, I'd like to know.)

Comment: Not to be too demanding, but I'd also like to verify whether "if [the new] question is positively received" means that it must receive a score of 1 or higher.  (In other words, is "'positively'" received supposed to be taken literally?)

Comment: The inner details of the algorithm are secret (even to moderators), so any information we gave you in that regard would be speculative.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24803/166791).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465424/106502) on March 9 (i.e. 3 months ago). According to [the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/380389) on the mother meta, you have to wait a full 6 months before asking another question:

> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask *one* new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

In other words, you had one chance in March and your question was not well-received so the ban was reinstated. You will have another chance in September.